# string index out of range

Tags: python, list

**Есть код**:

```py
categories = [0, 1, 2]
category = categories[1]
```

**При вызове выдает ошибку: `category = categories[1]`
`IndexError: string index out of range`**

**Не очень понимаю почему...**

Comment: Точно скопировал Ваш код и вызвал print(category), всё работает, выдаёт 1.

Comment: заметьте - **string** index, не list. Ищите, где там у вас строка